# Javascript canvas.toDataURL() returning Blank image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have the following code, which converts image to black and white:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var imgObj="data:image/png;base64,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";
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');


var imgW = 300;

var imgH = 300;
canvas.width = imgW;
canvas.height = imgH;

//canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);


for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
     for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
          var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
          var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
          imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
          imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
          imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
     }
}

canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);

console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
```

OUTPUT: `data:image/png;base64,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`

When when i open the result i see blank image!

I suspect its happening because i commented this line:

```
canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
```

But when i uncomment this line, i get:

```
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
```

How to solve this?

Pseudo Code

Input: a colorful image base64 string
output a black and white base64 string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking to get help with the `drawImage` call (and error), or your iterative approach that yields no output. Can you edit your question to just ask about the one approach that you want to use?

Answer (score 10):

Do it like this:

```
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

Then draw the image:

```
canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
```

Finally your code outputs a grayscale image in base64 string format.

`drawImage` wants an image object as the first argument, whereas you just give a base64 string (although it could produce an image).