# Copying image without a src to printable window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript project that TLDR creates a barcode. On the button click I want to print the barcode that gets generated by the internal `guid` I am using the `jsBarcode.js` plugin which takes a string and turns it into a barcode. Here is the html markup for that div.

```
<div id="printable">
    <img id="barcode"></img>
</div>
```

The barcode shows up perfectly it's just when trying to copy it over to a new window it doesnt show up :(

I have tried multiple ways of doing this and have had no luck. Right now I have this code and on the window that pops up it just shows `object Object`

```
var printContent = new $('#barcode').clone();
var w = window.open('','','width=340,height=260');

var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    windowContent += '<html>';
    windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title>';
    windowContent += '</head>';
    windowContent += '<body>';
    windowContent += '<img id="printWindowBarcode">' + printContent + '</img>';
    windowContent += '</body>';
    windowContent += '</html>';
    w.document.write(windowContent);
    w.focus();
    w.print();
    w.close();
```

I have had no luck with doing this.. I can make just text content show up now problem, but have no clue on how to do it when linking an image with no source... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the plugin page, example barcodes actually have sources : http://lindell.me/JsBarcode/ It's a base64 image, directly hardcoded into the image source. You can very well save/print base64 images.

Comment: `'<img id="printWindowBarcode">' + printContent + '</img>'` – is that how image elements are supposed to look in HTML? (Hint: If it was, I wouldn’t be asking …) And trying to concatenate a jQuery object into a string doesn’t make sense either.

Comment: @JeremyThille Do you know to access the source then? I was not aware it had a hardcoded src attached to it, so this should be a lot easier than I thought.

Comment: How to access the source? Simply with `$('#myImg').attr('src')` and voila, you get your base64 data. You can draw it on a canvas etc.

Comment: @JeremyThille So then when I go to re-draw the image I just would do `$('#barcode').getContext('src;);` ? (Sorry I havent used canvas really I just know of it... :(   )

Comment: Nope, have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas

Comment: @JeremyThille nevermind, I'm just going to try and keep it as an img and make the `src=$('#barcode').attr('src');` If you want to post an answer I'll accept it for you so you get your rep :)

Comment: @JeremyThille it works now thank you! Make an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Nice, did it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the plugin page, example barcodes actually have sources : lindell.me/JsBarcode It's a base64 image, directly hardcoded into the image source.
You can access the source simply with `$('#myImg').attr('src')` and voila, you get your base64 data. You can draw it on a canvas, etc. Have a look here : [Base64 png data to html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas)