# npm-canvas throws Image or Canvas expected

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm

**This has nothing to do with client side code. This is pure NodeJs**
I have this code for node which accepts base64 Image and resize the image to the specified h & w below.

NOTE: 
**imgData is the base64 image**

```
    var height = 148,
       width = 274,
       canvas = new Canvas(height, width),
       ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    ctx.drawImage(imgData, 0, 0, width, height);

    return canvas.toDataURL();
```

I see no problem with this but I am having an error on `ctx.drawImage(imgData, 0, 0, width, height);`

This is the error details:

`/vagrant/app/server/helpers/image_helper.js:41
        ctx.drawImage(imgData, 0, 0, width, height);
            ^
TypeError: Image or Canvas expected
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.module.exports.generateThumbnailImage (/vagrant/app/server/helpers/image_helper.js:41:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/app/server/service/blobstorage.js:35:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3`

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't show in your code where `imgData` is declared and initialised. What value does it have?

Comment: imgData is the base64 image passed in a parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 png data to html5 canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas)

Comment: Hint: a string is not an `Image` or a `Canvas`

Comment: Convert the base64 to an image. `var img = new Image(); img.src = imgData;`

Comment: Thank you @apsillers! Made me realize that I forgot the code that is answered by @Blindman67!