# chrome.browserAction.setIcon - Downloaded image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I want to make a Chrome addon, which displays ones Facebook picture.
Mine e.g. is [this one](https://graph.facebook.com/100004288501341/picture?type=square).

I do get the final Url and the response of an XMLHttpRequest.

In `response.response` I have the image data, which starts with `����JFIF���Photoshop 3.08BIM�gO87swNzt0qHGr_stQXIz(bFBMD01000aa00100001d020000b6020000ec02000027030`

I am trying to store and than display it. (I want to display this bigger on a different place as well). So I do not want to use `path` in `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`, but the Image itself.

I tried a lot of things (and will continue  tomorrow). So far:

- I need an `ImageData` Object
- I need an `ImageData` Object smaller than <= 19 pixels.
- I do know the size of the image from facebook (50x50)

Tomorrow I will continue with trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409745/1870799). I forgot, that the Image is not base64 encoded yet, so the solution linked in this sentence was not able to work...

My problem is: How to create the `ImageData`-Object(s) required by `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` frim the icon above in JS. Using the "html5-canvas" tag, as ImageData is very close to a canvas.

As always, answers are highly appreciated.

Yours,

Florian

Comment: Perhaps using the constructor. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook graph API does send the proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in the header of the image's response.

So all you need is to set the `crossorigin` attribute of an `<img>` tag to `'anonymous'`, draw this image onto a canvas and use either the imageData you get from `ctx.getImageData()` or the dataURI you get from `canvas.toDataURL()`.

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

img.onload = function(){
  c.width = this.width;
  c.height = this.height;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
  // either you do use the image data
  var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width, c.height);
  snippet.log('imagedata length : '+imagedata.data.length);
  // or the dataURL
  var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
  snippet.log(dataURL);
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+dataURL+')';
  }

img.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/100004288501341/picture?type=square"
```

```css
p{background-color: rgba(230, 230, 250,.7);}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```