# BlobURL for later usage

Tags: javascript, blob

I got BlobURL by this:

```
cnv.toBlob(blob=>{
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    localStorage.setItem("lorem",blobUrl)
})
```

Then I want to load it into canvas again on another time:

```
var blobUrl = localStorage.getItem("lorem")
fetch(blobUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        var img = new Image()
        img.onload = function() {
            cnv.ctx().drawImage(img, 0, 0)
        }
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error:",error))
```

I always got "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error, why? How to re-use Blob later?

Comment: Trying to `fetch` a blob URL ...? I don't think that makes any sense to begin with.

Comment: What function does BlobURL has? Why does Blob has URL? What do you do with URLs?

Comment: A blob URL only lives as long as the page that created it is alive. Storing to localStorage is of no use. Instead you'll want to save the `Blob` directly in the browser's IndexedDB.

Comment: For localstorage (so, string), you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring, and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas - just you may easily run into the size limit of URLs.

Comment: @Digerkam consider that right now your code tries to: 1.fetch an object URL 2. convert it to a blob 3. create an object URL from that blob 4. assign the object URL to the `src` attribute of an image. What object URLs are *for* is step 4. The fact that you have steps 1-3 which are redundant should be a hint that's not how you use  object URLs. Also, as Kaiido says - object URLs are short lived. Either until the document is unloaded or they can be prematurely pruned with [`URL.revokeObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL_static).

Comment: Why SO eagle to close questions?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800546/bloburl-for-later-usage#comment137155984_77800546) @Digerkam Closing duplicate questions improves the site's [signal-to-noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800546/bloburl-for-later-usage?noredirect=1#comment137156794_77800546) @Digerkam You can search on SO Meta and find lots of discussion about that, for example: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387333/438273)

Comment: @jsejcksn I see your point; but suggested link is not solving my problem, I was misunderstood the concept of blob, and closers misunderstood my question. This question deserves closing for ignority, not for dublication; but as the name of stackoverflow describes this site serves solving confusions while working on critical, time consuming problems, never serves as wiki; it cant.. While I am wallowing on terrible problems, vitnessing the people go hunting for "wrongs" for the sake of clean website that never needs is just weird. People are weird.. IndexedDB solved my problem btw. Thanks.